# How to get the number of Video files of device

Tags: iphone, xcode

i have to use number of video files of device with name to my app.
But i am not able to retrieve it,
Please Help me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'number of video files of device'?? you mean video files from gallery??

Comment: yes all file from galary

Comment: You could directly asked that you needed code not help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [use ALAssetsLibrary](https://github.com/siqin/TTImagePicker/blob/master/TTImagePicker/TTImagePickerController/TTAlbumTableController.m) to get the number of albums, photos or videos as you need.

For example, count the number of albums :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // !!! Notice : ALAssetsGroupAll doesn't include ALAssetsGroupLibrary.
    [_assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        if (group) {
            [self.groupArray addObject:group];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadTableView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Group not found!\n"); // Photo-access is disabled.
    }];
});
```

Then count the number of photos :

```
// Get count
ALAssetsGroup *group = (ALAssetsGroup*)[self.groupArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
NSInteger groupCount = [group numberOfAssets];
```

Attention that I [set the filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for allPhotos, you can set it for allVideos.

Answer (score 2):

An instance of [ALAssetsLibrary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) provides access to the videos and photos that are under the control of the Photos application. ALAssetsLibrary also includes contents in the Saved Photos album, from iTunes and also to the contents that are directly imported into the device. You can use it to retrieve the list of all asset groups and to save images and videos into the Saved Photos album.

Hope this will help.